# Given a List<int> how to create a comma separated string?

Tags: c#

Given a List<int> how to create a comma separated string?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1528733/259)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx):

```
List<int> myListOfInt = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

string result = string.Join<int>(", ", myListOfInt);

// result == "1, 2, 3, 4"
```

Comment: +1, Nice! But why is the type parameter on method `join` is not inferred?

Comment: @Jay Sinha: It is, but I wanted to make explicit that I'm using an overload of String.Join that has a type parameter. You can safely omit it.

Comment: With this code I get an error "error CS0308: The non-generic method 'string.Join(string, string[])' cannot be used with type arguments"

Comment: @DavidSykes: The generic overload of String.Join was added in .NET Framework 4. Are you perhaps using an earlier version?

Answer (score 0):

If it's going to be a large string, you may want to consider using the [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class because it is less memory intensive.  It doesn't allocate memory each time you append another string, which yields performance improvements.