# Efficient way to split List<int> into string

Tags: c#

I have a `List<int>` that can contain between 1 and n values.

Lets say their are four integers `{3,11,108,32}`
I need to construct the list of integers into a string like this

`(3,11,108,32)` - ie. Comma delimited

I realise this is very trivial, but I am looking for the most efficient solution.

For example, if you only have one item, there shouldn't be a comma in the string, but there should be between all additional items.

Comment: so your looking for a way to [`join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx) a list together?

Comment: Are you looking to build a IN clause dynamically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a List<int> to a comma separated list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528724/converting-a-listint-to-a-comma-separated-list)

Comment: Please share your _inefficient_ code.

Answer (score 6):

Use `String.Join` and `String.Format` to avoid creation of many in-memory sub-strings:

```
String.Format("({0})", String.Join(",", listOfIntegers))
```

Here two strings will be created. You can  also use `StringBuilder` and build string manually:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("(");
foreach (var value in listOfIntegers)
    builder.AppendFormat("{0},", value);
if (builder.Length > 1)
    builder.Remove(builder.Length - 1, 1);
builder.Append(")");
var result = builder.ToString();
```

But I would go with first approach, especially if list of integers is not very big.

Comment: +1 But i would really prefer `String.Join` since it's much more readable. It's also more efficient unless you don't want to concat millions of items. If i remember correctly it uses also a `StringBuilder` internally if required. Side-note: instead of `builder.Remove(builder.Length - 1, 1)` you can use `builder.Length--`

Answer (score 1):

If you use .NET 4+, you can use [`String.Join(String, IEnumerable<T>)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here an example on [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/);

```
List<int> ints  = new List<int>(){3, 11, 108, 32};
string joined = string.Join(",", ints);
string.Format("({0})", joined).Dump();
```

Output will be;

```
(3,11,108,32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm a big fan of Extension methods, I'll use one here.

First the extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void ForEachElement<T>(this IEnumerable<T> @enum, Action<T> mapFunction)
    {
        foreach (var item in @enum) mapFunction(item);
    }
}
```

This extension method allows me to, for each element in an Ienumerable, execute a specified action.

Then to format your list of int's to a string, you can do:

```
 var numbers = new List<int>() { 10, 11, 4, 5, 9, 12 };

 var sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.Append("(");
 numbers.ForEachElement(x => sb.Append(x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ","));

 string output = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(new[] { ',' }) + ")";
 MessageBox.Show(output);
```

This will produce the output:

(10,11,4,5,6,12)

Comment: Now it it. Sorry for the mistake.