# Printing a comma (,) after each item in an array

Tags: c#

Lets say I have an array (or list) of items

```
A[] = [a,b,c,d,e]
```

If I want to print them out so each item is separated by a comma (or any other delimiter), I generally have to do this:

```
for(int i=0; i < A.Count; i++)
{
    Console.Write(A[i]);

    if (i != A.Count-1)
        Console.Write(",");
}
```

So, my output looks like:

```
a,b,c,d,e
```

Is there a better or neater way to achieve this?

I like to use a foreach loop, but that prints a comma after the last element as well, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", A));
```

Comment: String is a class. string is a datatype. string.Join doesn't make sense symantically it should be String.Join

Comment: @HasanKhan There is [no difference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-s-the-difference-between-code-string-code-and-code-system-string-code.aspx) between `string` and `System.String`. It's a developer preference.

Comment: @vcsjones DUh! I know its an alias. The difference is in semantics and code readability. Methods on data type doesn't make sense.

Comment: ooh, nice! I wasn't aware of this. one question though: how could I use this if I had an array of object A where A has an int and a string data member? So, I want to do this on `A[i].string`?

Comment: @HasanKhan A class *is* a data type: `string` and `System.String` both refer to the same class, but the former is also a C# keyword. I agree with vscjones, using one or the other comes down to developer preference. Personally, I find `string.Join` more readable than the alternative as I never use `String`.

Comment: @xbonez you can do `string.Join(",", arrayOfAs.Select(a => a.StringMember))`

Comment: @BojanResnik http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for [`String.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx):

```
var list = String.join(",", A);
```

> `String.Join` Method `(String, String[])`
>
> Concatenates all the elements of a string array, using the specified separator between each element.
>
> ```
> public static string Join(
>     string separator,
>     params string[] value
> )
> ```

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a better or neater way to achieve this? I like to use a foreach loop, but that prints a comma after the last element as well, which is undesirable.

As others have said, `Join` does the right thing. But here's another way to think about the problem that might help you in the future. Instead of thinking of the problem as *put a comma after every element except the last element* -- which you correctly note makes it difficult to work with the "foreach" loop -- think of the problem as *put a comma before every element except the first element*. Now it is easy to do with a foreach loop!

For about a million more ways to solve a similar problem see:

[Eric Lippert's challenge "comma-quibbling", best answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788535/eric-lipperts-challenge-comma-quibbling-best-answer)

And the original blog post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/15/comma-quibbling.aspx

Comment: I have actually considered it as a 'put a comma before every element but the first one' and still been unable to solve it with a foreach. Maybe I'm missing something obvious. Looking into your links now for, hopefully, a better understanding. Thanks for the links.

Comment: @xbonez : "Put a comma before every element but the first one" is done by using a conditional on a `bool` that is changed within the loop.  For example, `if (!isFirstElement){sb.Append(",");}isFirstElement=false;`

Answer (score 4):

Use the [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) method, very handy.

```
String.Join(",", my_array)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

`String.Join(",", arrayOfStrings);`

Answer (score 2):

```
string separator = String.Empty;
for(int i=0; i < A.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write(seperator);
    Console.Write(A[i]);
    separator = ",";
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This appears to be a sensible solution. (Though "separator" is misspelled.)

Comment: I'm definitely +1ing this one. This is what I do most of the time to solve this kind of problem, though I usually use a StringBuilder and foreach

Comment: Eric, do you actually like this solution? I feel that setting separator in every iteration makes the code very difficult to read. [And no, I didn't down vote but I won't up vote this answer either.]

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] values = new string[]{"banana", "papaya", "melon"};

        var result = values.Aggregate((x,y) => x + ", " + y);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```