# Stick delineated between array elegantly

Tags: arrays, string

Anytime I need to make a string from a list that has some kind of delineation I have something like

```
string output = "";
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    output += array[i] + ", ";
return output;
```

But this always adds a comma to the end where I don't want it. To avoid that I have to do

```
string output = "";
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    output += array[i];
    if(i != array.length - 1)
        output += ", ";
return output;
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this goal?

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: @user2488335 In that case, something like this would probably be more useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682560/printing-a-comma-after-each-item-in-an-array

Comment: Wow, that's a very nice function that I never know about. I really ought to check the string library more often for things like this. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is:

```
string output = array[0];
for(int i=1; i<array.length; i++)
    output += ", " + array[i];
return output;
```