# What's the best way to merge strings?

Tags: c#, string, coding-style

Let's say I have a foreach-loop with strings like this:

```
String newStr='';
String str='a b c d e';
foreach(String strChar in str.split(' ')) {
  newStr+=strChar+',';
}
```

the result would be something like: `a,b,c,d,e,` but what I want is `a,b,c,d,e` without the last comma. I normally split the last comma out but this seems ugly and overweight. Is there any lightweight way to do this?

Additional to this question: Is there any easy solution to add an "and" to the constellation that the result is something like: `a, b, c, d and e` for user output?

p.s.: I know that I can use the replace-method in the example but this is not what I'm looking because in most cases you can't use it (for example when you build a sql string).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use `string.Join`:

```
string newStr = string.Join(",", str.Split(' '));
```

Alternatively, you could add the separator at the *start* of the body of the loop, but *not* on the first time round.

I'd suggest using `StringBuilder` if you want to keep doing this by hand though. In fact, with a `StringBuilder` you could just unconditionally append the separator, and then decrement the length at the end to trim that end.

You also wrote:

> for example when you build a sql string

It's very rarely a good idea to build a SQL string like this. In particular, you should absolutely **not** use strings from user input here - use parameterized SQL instead. Building SQL is typically the domain of ORM code... in which case it's usually better to use an existing ORM than to roll your own :)

Comment: What is ORM? Object Role Modeling?

Comment: I'am using LINQ. Is this a ORM?

Comment: @JanHommes: Yes. (Or rather, LINQ comes in several different flavours, but most of the db-related ones would count as ORMs.) If you're using LINQ, why would you be creating a SQL statement yourself at all?

Comment: To do a fulltext search on a dynamical created grid. It's not SQL, but SQL-Like with dynamic-LINQ. Is there any better solution for a fulltext search?

Comment: @JanHommes: We'd need to know more about *exactly* what you were doing... but in general you shouldn't need to include values in strings for queries. It's fraught with problems.

Comment: thx for your help. Join and Stringbuilder helped me and I will review my concept.

Answer (score 4):

you're characterizing the problem as appending a comma after every string except the last. Consider characterizing it as prepending a comma before every string but the first. It's an easier problem.

As for your harder version there are several dozen solutions on my blog and in this question.

[Eric Lippert's challenge "comma-quibbling", best answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788535/eric-lipperts-challenge-comma-quibbling-best-answer)

Answer (score 2):

[`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) may be your friend:

```
String str='a b c d e';
var newStr = string.Join(",", str.Split(' '));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do it where you have "and" before the last value.

```
var vals = str.Split(' ');
var ans = vals.Length == 1 ?
          str :
          string.Join(", ", vals.Take(vals.Length - 1))) + ", and " + vals.Last();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newStr = String.Join(",", str.split(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Regex` and replace whitespaces with commas

```
string newst = Regex.Replace(input, " ", ",");
```

Comment: Why bother with `Regex.Replace` when there's `string.Replace` and the expression is so simple?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be using a StringBuilder for string manipulations of this sort. Second, it's just an if conditional on the insert.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder newStr = new System.Text.StringBuilder("");
string oldStr = "a b c d e";

foreach(string c in oldStr.Split(' ')) {
    if (newStr.Length > 0) newStr.Append(",");
    newStr.Append(c);
}
```